How to convert image to simple line drawing in Android?
I am developing an Android app and I want to convert an image obtained from the device library into a simple line drawing. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you all


This library helpful for you, check it:

https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage

